# Building shopping cart with two rows for one product

Tags: php, wordpress, forms, shopping-cart

I'am trying to build shopping cart where cart row id is product_id but I need it to be like that: where I can enter two same products to shopping cart but width different color attribute. Width form post I post 'id' and 'color'. Code so far:

```
<?php
    require('../../../wp-config.php');
    mysql_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD);
    if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    $id=intval($_POST['id']);

    if (isset($_SESSION['cart'][$id]) && $_SESSION['cart'][$id]['color'] == $_POST['color']) {

        $_SESSION['cart'][$id]['quantity']++;
        $link =str_replace( '?action=added_to_cart', '', $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] );
        header('location:' . $link . '?action=added_to_cart');

    } else {

        $sql_s="SELECT * FROM wp_posts WHERE ID=($id)";
        $query_s=mysql_query($sql_s);
        if(mysql_num_rows($query_s)!=0) {
            $row_s=mysql_fetch_array($query_s);
            if ($_POST['color'] == 'gray') {
                $price = get_price($id);
            } else {
                $price = get_price_colored_stones($id);
            }
            $_SESSION['cart'][$row_s['ID']]=array(
                "quantity" => 1,
                "price" => $price,
                "color" => $_POST['color']
            );
            $link =str_replace( '?action=added_to_cart', '', $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] );
            header('location:' . $link . '?action=added_to_cart');
        } else {
            $message="This product id is invalid!";
        }
    }
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So this is what I did:
I made shopping cart row id like that [id_color]. So now there can be products in shoppingcart width same product_id two different rows in shopping cart('gray' and 'colored'). Later I remove color with str_replace, so I can get pure product id width what I can query product information.
And code:

```
<?php
require('../../../wp-config.php');
mysql_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD);
if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    $id=intval($_POST['id']);

    if (isset($_SESSION['cart'][$id  . '_' .  $_POST['color']])) {

    $_SESSION['cart'][$id  . '_' .  $_POST['color']]['quantity']++;
    $link =str_replace( '?action=added_to_cart', '', $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] );
    header('location:' . $link . '?action=added_to_cart');

} else {

    $sql_s="SELECT * FROM wp_posts WHERE ID=($id)";
    $query_s=mysql_query($sql_s);
    if(mysql_num_rows($query_s)!=0) {
        $row_s=mysql_fetch_array($query_s);
        if (!isset($_POST['color'])){
            $_POST['color'] = 'gray';
        }
        if ($_POST['color'] == 'gray') {
            $price = get_price($id);
        } else {
            $price = get_price_colored_stones($id);
        }
        $_SESSION['cart'][$row_s['ID'] . '_' .  $_POST['color']]=array(
            "quantity" => 1,
            "price" => $price,
            "color" => $_POST['color'],
            "title" => $row_s['post_title']
        );
        $link =str_replace( '?action=added_to_cart', '', $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] );
        header('location:' . $link . '?action=added_to_cart');
    } else {
        $message="This product id is invalid!";
        }
    }
}
```